PYTHON: Qiskit library import
I'm trying to implement old code on qiskit whose imports start with
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import BasicAer, execute
from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
import cmath

the error comes from the 2nd line

ImportError: cannot import name 'BasicAer' from 'qiskit' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/init.py)

I think the problem comes from an old version of qiskit but when I try an old version I have a problem with self "cannot import name 'Self' from 'typing_extensions'."
Someone would have any idea ? ty
I don't have the exact qiskit version of the code I'm trying to implement but the code dates from August 2019

BasicAer is form older versions of qiskit. And the Self command won't be compatible with older Python. Why do you need the old code? Can we help you update this to the current version commands?

If you were using the most recent version of Qiskit, you were probably using version 0.11 or 0.12 (see https://pypi.org/project/qiskit/#history). These versions of Qiskit only work with Python 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7, you'll need to use one of those versions.
Try installing Python 3.7 and creating a new virtual environment. Here's how you create a virtual environment and activate it on a Unix-like system.
python3.7 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install qiskit==0.11

Then try running your program.

The qiskit.providers.basicaer module is deprecated as of Qiskit 0.46 and will be removed in Qiskit 1.0. Its functionality has been replaced by the new qiskit.providers.basic_provider module and the qiskit.quantum_info module.
from qiskit.providers.basic_provider import BasicProvider
backend = BasicProvider().get_backend('basic_simulator')


Transpile has a different functionality from the previous backend.run() method. I am facing similar issues too. Check out this doc for some feature changes
https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/qiskit-1.0-features#execute
Using the V2 sampler seems alright
